# Converting rows to columns and keeping data pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following problem in MSSQL: I have a table, which contains 4 columns.

Example table:

```
JunctionId | type| color| value
 1 |  a | red | 5|
 1 |  b | green | 10|
 2 |  a | orange | 40|
 2 |  b | yellow | 35|
 3 |  a | blue | 6|
 3 |  b | cyan | 9|
```

Now, I'd like the following result:

```
1 | a | red | 5 | b | green | 10
2 | a | orange | 40 | b | yellow | 35
3 | a | blue | 6 | b | cyan | 9
```

I tried using PIVOT, but it was returning multiple rows because of the different values. I would use selfjoin, but I have 12 different 'type'. Any ideas would be very welcomed!

(note: I can't use this stackoverflow table thingy... sorry)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Self join time

```
select a1.junctionid, 
       a1.type as a_type,
       a1.color as a_color,
       a1.value as a_value, 
       a2.type as b_type, 
       a2.color as b_color, 
       a2.value as b_value
from MyTable a1
inner join MyTable a2
on a1.junctionid = a2.junctionid
where a1.type = 'a'
and a2.type = 'b'
```

Comment: Yea, but as I said, I really wouldn't like to use self join, since I have 12 different types. But looks like I am going to, because I cannot use procedures :/ Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.